# Does Windows 7 Starter still have 3-application limit

Tags: windows-7

Most cheapest netbooks have Starter edition of Windows 7 which had 3-application limit. Is the limit still there after Windows 7 is on the market for a few months. I couldn't find anything about the limit on the Microsoft site and this is something that really bothers me because it's likely that I will need more then three apps running simultanously.

Comment: If you need more than 3 apps running at once, you shouldn't be going for win7 starter.

Comment: If you need more than 3 apps running at once, you shouldn't be going for a netbook. :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I just need something ultra-portable. Already got 2 full-size laptops and a PC. But I know that sooner or later I'd need to run forth app and it would be a problem. But fortunatelly the limit is removed.

Comment: Cmon folks this isn't an iPad, of course a Netbook user would like to run more than 3 apps at a time, even if it is still starter edition of windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not here any more. They removed it.

For example, read [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/05/microsoft-kills-3-application-limit-for-windows-7-starter.ars) or [others](http://windows7news.com/2009/05/30/windows-7-starter-3-app-limit-officially-removed/).